# Find direct & indirect method usages if method is overriden in base class

Tags: ndepend

please, help me to figure out how to write the query :)

The code is:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var man = new Man("Joe");

            Console.WriteLine(man.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class SuperMan
    {
        public SuperMan(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name;
        }

        string name;
    }

    public class Man : SuperMan
    {
        public Man(string name) : base(name)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find all direct and indirect dependencies (methods) to Man.ToString(). There is only one call in Main() method.

The query I'm trying is:

```
from m in Methods 
let depth0 = m.DepthOfIsUsing("ConsoleApplication1.SuperMan.ToString()")
where depth0  >= 0 orderby depth0
select new { m, depth0 }.
```

but it doesn't find dependent Program.Main() method....

How to modify query so that it finds usages for such kind of methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's look at direct callers. We want to list all methods that calls `SuperMan.ToString()` or any `ToString()` methods overriden by `SuperMan.ToString()`. It can looks like:

```
let baseMethods = Application.Methods.WithFullName("ConsoleApplication1.SuperMan.ToString()").Single().OverriddensBase
from m in Application.Methods.UsingAny(baseMethods)
where m.IsUsing("ConsoleApplication1.Man")  // This filter can be added
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

Notice we put a filter clause, because in the real world pretty much every method calls `object.ToString()` (this is a particular case).

Now to handle indirect calls this is more tricky. We need to call the magic [FillIterative()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ExtensionMethodsHelpers~FillIterative.html) extension methods on generic sequences.

```
let baseMethods = Application.Methods.WithFullName("ConsoleApplication1.SuperMan.ToString()").Single().OverriddensBase
let recursiveCallers = baseMethods.FillIterative(methods => methods.SelectMany(m => m.MethodsCallingMe))

from pair in recursiveCallers 
let method = pair.CodeElement
let depth = pair.Value
where method.IsUsing("ConsoleApplication1.Man") // Still same filter
select new { method , depth }
```

Et voilà!

[image: NDepend Code Query Direct Indirect Method Call]